# Updating subdocuments in mongodb (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a the following collection

```
Channels [
 {
   _id:1
   users:[
    {
     _id:1
     skipRounds:1
    },
    {
     _id:2
     skipRounds:3
    },       
   ]
 },
 {
   _id:2
   users:[
    {
     _id:1
     skipRounds:3
    },
    {
     _id:2
     skipRounds:5
    },       
   ]
 },   
]
```

I'd like to know how to decrement the value of skipRounds property on the users subcollection. Can anyone tell me how to do this with mongodb node.js client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) to decrement and [positional $[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#up._S_[]) to apply it to all elements. E.g:

```
db.Channels.updateMany(
    {"users.skipRounds": {$exists:true}}, 
    {$inc: {"users.$[].skipRounds": -1}}
);
```